# jQuery getElementByClassName works but not always

Tags: jquery

I have this bit of jQuery that works perfectly as wanted but not always, sometimes it does not work until I refresh the page again, I don't know why.

All I want is to disable the main screen from scrolling when the sidebar is open and make it scroll when its closed (the side bar only appears if the window is small).

Here is my jQuery for that:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".sidebar-mobile-icon").click(function() {
    var sideBar = $(".shop-sidebar");
    for (var i = 0; i < sideBar.length; i++) {
        $("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
        if(sideBar.hasClass("opened")) {
            $("html").css("overflow", "scroll");
        }   
    }
});
});
```

It can be tested if you visit my website: outfityard.com , the problem is in the sidebar but it only appears with a small window browser.

Comment: I have tried to fix my code and not to mix vanilla JS with jQuery but still getting the same result, you can find my new code above

Comment: @BramVanroy is that what you mean?

Comment: Try setting the sidebar container height to 100vh and set the overflow scroll in the container  to auto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you use the for-loop, but this should work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".sidebar-mobile-icon").click(function() {
      if ($(".shop-sidebar").hasClass("opened")) {
        $("html, body").css("overflow", "scroll");
      } else {
        $("html, body").css("overflow", "hidden");
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks mate its much better than what I had but its still not working as expected you can test it on the website www.outfityard.com, it looks that it does not work if you scrolled the main body down then up to the top again after that opened the sidebar it will not lock the body scroll

Comment: I made a typo. Try again. Also I highly advise to minmise the JS files.

Comment: I have compered this code with the one you posted earlier there is no difference can you tell me what is the typo

Comment: I have figured out what was the problem, my problem was with the $(".sidebar-mobile-icon").click(function()) as this is applied only on the small icon that opens the side bar and not the sidebar-toggle so if the sidebar-toggle is pressed the function won't work but i have to press on the icon it self, so I have edited the function to this:     $(".sidebar-toggle").click(function())  many thanks for your help mate.

Comment: But why it does not work on mobile browser, I'm using iPhone 6s

Comment: Probably it's cached on your phone. Try emptying cache and browser history.

Comment: No its not about caching I have been reading about it and I had to add $("html, body").css("position", "relative"); but this introduced a new bug which makes the scroll position get lost when I open the side bar so I'm trying to fix that now, many thanks for your help mate, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Apply style to the body, not html element.